# Broken screen phone as wifi hotspot

Tags: wireless, android, remote, tethering, adb

I have dropped my android phone (Galaxy Ace 3), and unfortunately screen is not working.
Is there anyway to turn on usb tethering or wifi hotspot remotly via usb with my ubuntu?(yes, the phone works fine, beside the screen)

I was trying to use adb, but i can't see my phone in `adb devices`

Any idea how to do it?

I don't have debugging usb mode on.
After connecting phone to usb it appears in lsusb, and have access to files.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are unable to connect with the adb is because your phone must not have USB debugging installed.

You cant connect through adb unless you somehow enable it.

As a semi solution, you could go and get a dirt cheap screen repair, and even if it doesn't last, you can at least enable the USB debugging!

Good Luck